# Creating an rvalue and passing it to a function by forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, reference

I have this code which *seems* to work, but I'm not sure if I'm just seeing undefined behaviour or it's actually working.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {

    const std::vector<std::string> keywords = {
        "and","and_eq","asm","auto","bitand", "bitor","bool","break","case",
        "catch","char","class","compl","const", "const_cast","continue",
        "default","#define","delete","do","double","dynamic_cast","else","enum",
        "explicit","export","extern", "extern \"C\"","false","float",
        "for","friend","goto","if","inline","int","long","mutable","namespace",
        "new","not","not_eq","operator","or", "or_eq","private","protected",
        "public","register","reinterpret_cast","short","signed","sizeof",
        "static","static_cast","struct","switch","template","this","throw",
        "true","try","typedef","typeid","typename","union","unsigned","using",
        "virtual","void","volatile","void","wchar_t","while","xor","xor_eq",
        "return", "decltype"
    };

    std::ostringstream keywords_pattern =
        std::accumulate(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), std::forward<std::ostringstream>(
            std::ostringstream("constexpr", std::ostringstream::ate)),
            [](std::ostringstream &accum, const std::string& next) -> std::ostringstream&& {
                accum << '|' << next;
                return std::forward<std::ostringstream>(std::move(accum));
            });

    std::cout << keywords_pattern.str() << std::endl;
}
```

### What it does:

All this does is combine the vector of C++ keywords into a string seperated by `|`.

### Output:

This is the output when I run it:

```
 onstexpr|and|and_eq|asm|auto|bitand|bitor|bool|break|case|catch|char|class|compl|const|const_cast|continue|default|#define|delete|do|double|dynamic_cast|else|enum|explicit|export|extern|extern "C"|false|float|for|friend|goto|if|inline|int|long|mutable|namespace|new|not|not_eq|operator|or|or_eq|private|protected|public|register|reinterpret_cast|short|signed|sizeof|static|static_cast|struct|switch|template|this|throw|true|try|typedef|typeid|typename|union|unsigned|using|virtual|void|volatile|void|wchar_t|while|xor|xor_eq|return|decltype
```

**No** this is not a mistake, it is indeed missing the first character from the output, even though I fail to see how, hence the more reason why I felt certain there was something I was doing wrong.

### My concerns:

I am especially worried it might have some undefined behaviour because the function is manipulating a temporary (the ostringstream) through a reference; and finally returning...*an rvalue reference*??

That's where I need help with understanding how to make sure I am not doing something wrong. Also, with my use of forwarding and move semantics, are there any improvements I can make there? Suggest away.

### Compiled with:

Compiles with no warnings or errors on GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 5):

## `std::accumulate`, `std::ostringstream` and the standard

`std::accumulate` requires that `T` (the return type and the type of the initial value) is `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`. `std::ostringstream` is neither `CopyAssignable` nor `CopyConstructible`, so as far as the standard is concerned, it's not allowed. (In fact, MSVC throws a big red error in your face!).

Interestingly, neither GCC nor clang nor icc (the ons i tested) produce even a warning (with `-pedantic`), though I don't know whether that's a bug (doesn't warn about `std::ostringstream` not being `CopyAssignable` or `CopyConstructible`) or a feature (do they explicitly support move-only types for `std::accumulate`?).

Anyways, even if they were to support it, it's not in the standard, so they could technically do as they want.

TLDR: It isn't allowed according to the standard.

## Implementation

There's no need for `std::forward` in this code.

In the first usage, the `std::ostringstream` constructor already returns a rvalue reference.

In the second usage, you already explicitly turned `accum` into a rvalue reference by calling `std::move`.

`std::forward` is useful in templates, where the type of the variable to be forwarded gets deduced, so you don't know whether it can/should be moved or copied. Example:

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(T&& thing) {
    call_impl(std::forward<T>(thing));
}

do_something(std::string("text")); // calls call_impl(std::string&&);

std::string example{"text"};
do_something(example); // calls call_impl(std::string&) or call_impl(const std::string&)
```

Also, consider replacing `std::endl` with `'\n'`, unless you explicitly want to flush the stream.

Comment: All your comments are correct, but after taking all your comments, the resulting code should not have corrupted the first character.
You never mention the corrupted first character.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle: I don't mention the first character, because going by the standard, the code given that leads to the error isn't conforming, so anything could happen. If it's just a missing character instead of, say, a corrupted hard drive, consider yourself lucky! Yes, digging a bit deeper, it seems to be a bug with moving or move-assigning `std::ostringstream`, but as far as I am concerned, that's not an issue with OP's code, but a bug in the compiler provided standard library implementation, which in this case is caused by calling another function of said library in an unspecified way.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the use of forwarding. Also I took a look at the documentation for [`CopyAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), and as far as I can tell, the only requirement is that the object is [`MoveAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable), which as of c++11, it looks like [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream) is `MoveAssignable`. So I think the only thing missing is `CopyConstructible`. But should this be the reason, seeing as I solely use an rvalue?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue (the corrupted first character) can be reduced to the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream myStream("constexpr", std::ostringstream::ate);
    myStream = std::move(myStream);
    std::cout << myStream.str() <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Which sure looks like a bug in GCC to me.**

It works fine in Visual Studio 2013 but the problem is reproduced with
mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0

Comment: @Tarc has a valid point. If I change it to `std::ostringstream myStream(std::move(std::ostringstream("constexpr", std::ostringstream::ate)));`, then the full string is printed out. Tested on multiple versions of clang and gcc 6.3/5.4

Comment: @smac89, you don't need `std::move` when you pass a temporary, it's an rvalue anyway.